# Php include_once not working, nothing showing up

Tags: php

I am just beginning to learn php.

I am attempting to use the include_once function in order to include a template header in each of my php sites.

(also, this is my first post on this site, and I am not quite sure how it works... just realized the 4-space indent thing)

I am watching this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65gV8JOgWkQ&feature=relmfu

And beginning at about minute 19:00, I have entered this code into DW CS5 as advised.

This is my index.php file:

```
<body>

<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
<?php inlude_once("/Users/patrickmeaney/localhost/BobsSuits/template_header.php"); ?>

<?php include_once     dirname("/Users/patrickmeaney/localhost/BobsSuits/template_header.php"); ?>

<div id="pageContent"> test</div>
<?php inlude_once("template_footer.php");?>

</div>



</body>
```

This is my template_header page:

```
<div id="pageHeader"><table width="100%" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td width="49%"><img src="style/bobssuitslogo.png" width="433" height="92" alt="Logo" /></td>
    <td width="51%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><a href="index.php">Home</a> <a href="#">Link 1</a> <a href="#">Link 2</a> <a href="#">Link 3</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm going to upvote this, because I don't agree with downvoting it and not leaving any comments. @PatrickMeaney, did you check your server's error logs? Most likely that's where your error message is.

Comment: Turn on error reporting. (`inlude_once`)

Comment: If you're trying to learn PHP, you should probably avoid any tutorials that use DreamWeaver.

Comment: Corbin, may I ask why you advise against DreamWeaver?  And, what would you suggest I substitute in its place?  Thank you

Comment: Mike & Waleed, thanks for the comments.  I'm using MAMP, and I'm pretty new to any kind of web development, so I will try to figure that out.

Comment: @PatrickMeaney I've never used DW for any extended amount of time, so I can't speak to it as a product, but there tends to be a correlation between people who use DW and people who have no idea what they're talking about PHP-wise.  Having glanced through that video, there's nothing *horribly* wrong with it, but there's a ton of little items that guy got completely wrong.  Also, WYSIWYG editors are basically antiproductive.  No one uses Frontpage anymore, and there's a reason why (well, there's a million reasons why).

Comment: Anyway, the standard approach is to use either an editor like Notepad++, or vim, or to use an IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse.  Once again, I've not used DW much, so I can't say for sure, but I'm guessing that something like Netbeans will be a lot more conducive to PHP programming.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, I would suggest using [require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) and not include (or their `_once` versions)

> require is identical to include except upon failure it will also
> produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. In other words, it will
> halt the script whereas include only emits a warning (E_WARNING) which
> allows the script to continue.

This makes it a lot easier for you to identify where the error is.

Now in your code you have:

```
include_once dirname("/Users/patrickmeaney/localhost/BobsSuits/template_header.php");
```

which is wrong because you are using the [dirname](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) command. `dirname` will return a folder, in your case "/Users/patrickmeaney/localhost/BobsSuits" and will not include the file name in the end.

I would suggest removing the dirname making the include statement as follows:

```
include_once "/Users/patrickmeaney/localhost/BobsSuits/template_header.php";
```

Comment: Nikolaos,  Thanks for your help.  
  Just to clarify, I was using "include_once dirname" as an experiment to see if it would work, since "include_once" was not working  (I had no idea what it would do, so thanks for letting me know).

...So, since you recommend require instead of include, would recommend this?:

    require("/Users/patrickmeaney/localhost/BobsSuits/template_header.php");

Comment: You are correct. You can also use the `require_once` function for that. The difference is that `require` and `require_once` will halt the program, giving you more information on what is going on in your application irrespective of what your error settings are (include provides a E_NOTICE and if your php is set to ignore notices you won't see what is going on). Additionally having xdebug installed in your development environment will provide invaluable information on what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will look into xdebug, I hope its compatible with DW .  What development environment do you use Nikolaos?

Comment: I have used almost all of them. I started with Eclipse but on large projects it was really slow and memory hungry. Then I used Sublime Text 2, which is blistering fast but lacks class discovery. I ended up using PHPStorm which has all the features I want and it is fast. All of the above (apart from Eclipse which is free) have evaluation versions so you can try them first. xDebug is something that installs with PHP so it works just fine. DW might have a helper in it to give you more info but your source of info is always the server logs :)